# Converting a sensor value using simple arithmetic

Tags: sensors

I am currently working on a light sensor. I managed to make the sensor work. But I want to change the value of the sensor being shown by multiplying it with 0.002 with a press of a button. I can't seem to get the code of the button to multiply because it keeps saying operator (*) cannot be applied to java.lang.String, double. I have tried the double.parse but can't seems to get to work. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

TextView textView;

SensorManager sensorManager;
Sensor sensor;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Service.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View multiply) {
            textView.setText(Integer.parseInt(textView.getText().toString()*0.002));

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    if (sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT) {
        textView.setText("" + sensorEvent.values[0]);
    }

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {

}
```

Comment: You should [edit] the question and show the text of the stacktrace. That being said, you clearly cannot multiply a string of characters with a double. It looks like you want to update the text of that control with a new value you derive. I'd make a function that knows how to take text, convert it to a numeric value, multiple that by some factor, and then turn it back to a string. But you should be clear about what you are doing,

Comment: @jdv this shows when I run the app/ error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
first type:  String
second type: double The textView is in numeric value with the unit of lux. I'm having difficulty in multiplying it with 0.002. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: SO isn't a threaded forum. Edit the question and put these details in it so everything is in one place. But, really. The code shows you trying to multiply a string.